# Global variables

Tags: vba, for-loop

Here is my looping code which works great

```
i = 3
Do
Cells(i, 8) = 17012
i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 11
```

I would like the "loop until i=11" to read more like " loop until i=f" or some other variable letter is not  important. I want F to represent the value of the number of times another button is pressed. The code below represents the count of clicks. But is under another cmd button.

```
Static Counter As Integer
Counter = Counter + 1
cmdworkstationadd.Caption = Counter
```

So my thinking is the code for output would be:

```
i = 3
Do
Cells(i, 8) = 17012
i = i + 1
Loop Until i = F
```

but f has no value so looping never stops because F is seen as 0. how can I set the value of the counter to F so that F has value

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you declare your variables:

```
Option Explicit
Public Counter As Integer

Sub SetCounter()
    Counter = 15
End Sub

Sub PrintCounter()
    Debug.Print Counter
End Sub
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278427.aspx

Comment: I declared my public or global variable at the top of the coding. what does option explict do exactly? When I use it my code stops working were before it worked just fine. It works great right now without it really. I need to know how to assign a letter value for the counter so I can use it in another area of my code

Comment: Option Explicit means that you must declare your variables. It is good practice, and if your code fails with Option Explicit, there may be problems waiting to happen. If you mean you wish to set a variable to the name of a variable and then reference that, it is not possible in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Always use

```
Option Explicit
```

... doing so, most errors will show up before they actually happen.